# 18.04.6 LTS 5.4.0-132 kernel reserving 30GB memory

Tags: kernel, ram

I recently upgraded my kernel version from 5.4.0-131 to 5.4.0-132. I noticed some lagging behavior after this upgrade, and when I checked my memory usage with `free -h`, it was reporting a total of 2.2G.

I looked with `dmesg` to see what it would show regarding memory:

```
[    0.277055] Memory: 2158340K/33356064K available (14339K kernel code, 2375K rwdata, 9460K rodata, 2740K init, 4988K bss, 31197724K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Why is the kernel reserving over 30GB of memory?

Comparing to 5.4.0-131, there's a big difference:

```
[    0.290845] Memory: 32491976K/33356064K available (14339K kernel code, 2375K rwdata, 9448K rodata, 2740K init, 4988K bss, 864088K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

I compared `/proc/iomem` between kernel versions and saw no significant differences.

What else can I check to see why the kernel is reserving so much more with this later kernel version?

EDIT: I noticed this in `dmesg` as well with the 132 kernel, which might point to an issue? The limit of -2 sounds rather off to me.

```
[    0.015406] MEMBLOCK configuration:
[    0.015407]  memory size = 0x00000007f3e48000 reserved size = 0xffffffff4fff5e19
[    0.015408]  memory.cnt  = 0x7
[    0.015410]  memory[0x0]     [0x0000000000001000-0x000000000005bfff], 0x000000000005b000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015411]  memory[0x1]     [0x000000000005d000-0x000000000009ffff], 0x0000000000043000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015413]  memory[0x2]     [0x0000000000100000-0x00000000970f1fff], 0x0000000096ff2000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015414]  memory[0x3]     [0x00000000970f3000-0x0000000097903fff], 0x0000000000811000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015415]  memory[0x4]     [0x0000000097905000-0x00000000b66aafff], 0x000000001eda6000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015416]  memory[0x5]     [0x00000000b7c0f000-0x00000000b7c0ffff], 0x0000000000001000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015417]  memory[0x6]     [0x0000000100000000-0x000000083d7fffff], 0x000000073d800000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015418]  reserved.cnt  = 0x6
[    0.015420]  reserved[0x0]   [0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000000fff], 0x0000000000001000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015421]  reserved[0x1]   [0x000000003a3e2000-0x000000003d08bfff], 0x0000000002caa000 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015422]  reserved[0x2]   [0x00000000a09ef018-0x00000000a09efbb7], 0x0000000000000ba0 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015423]  reserved[0x3]   [0x00000000a09f0018-0x00000000a0a00057], 0x0000000000010040 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015425]  reserved[0x4]   [0x00000000a4f9d018-0x00000000a4fa5269], 0x0000000000008252 bytes flags: 0x0
[    0.015426]  reserved[0x5]   [0x00000000b2cce018-0xfffffffffffffffe], 0xffffffff4d331fe7 bytes flags: 0x0
```

EDIT 2: I have uploaded both `dmesg` outputs: [5.4.0-131](https://pastebin.com/0t9qwgUG) and [5.4.0-132](https://pastebin.com/pgYjzqtK) in hopes these will shed some further light on the situation.

Comment: 5.4.0-131 and 5.4.0-132 and others are very similar for me ~864000K reserved.

Comment: In short: it doesn't - except for a few seconds during boot. What is the output of `free -h`on your system?

Comment: @vidarlo If you're asking me, I've listed the `free` usage above: 2.2G. Comparing more of the `dmesg` log, it seems like this has something to do with EFI memory allocation.